# Moved Wordpress site, can not login as admin anymore

Tags: wordpress, authentication, admin

I've moved my local copy of wp to my production site and did all the annoying stuff you have to do when moving WP around.

My only issue now is that I can not login anymore to my WP as admin. The user gets logged in but obviously does not have it's admin permissions.

I've already checked the serialized permission array for that user and it seems to be correct but my user still gets not recognized as an admin type user.

Any ideas what the cause of this issue could be?

Edit: Solved, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue:

I have not seen anywhere in the documentation that WP obviously uses the db prefix for it's table wp2_usermeta and its meta_key field.

So somehow I've ended up with wp2_capabilities AND wp_capabilities. The wp2_ one was wrong. It did not migrate or change this properly.

If wordpress is ever going to get unit tests and proper migrations with rollback and changelogs...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you migrated the database entirely to the new location, if admin is missing permisions of its role, edit them manually in the database table `wp_usermeta`, field `wp_user_level`

Comment: Thank you, this was one of the first thing's I've checked, but see the answer I found shortly after I wrote the question when i looked at *all* meta_key records for the user.